# GridView inside p:dataScroller

Tags: jsf, gridview, primefaces

I tried with the following code to create a "Facebook" like GridView. I am sure I am doing something completely wrong here (since I am novice programmer) You people have any idea how I could achieve that? I know DataGrid exists but I wanted to try something that was scrollable:

```
<p:dataScroller id="profilePhotos"
                var="photo"
                value="#{searchController.photoModel}"
                chunkSize="3"
                lazy="true">

    <p:panelGrid columns="3">
        <f:facet name="loader">
            <p:commandLink type="button"
                           value="load more"
                           icon="ui-icon-circle-triangle-s" />
        </f:facet>

        <p:media rendered="#{photo.id ne 0}"
                 value="imageservlet?id=#{photo.id}" width="400" height="400"
                 player="quicktime" />
        <br />

        <p:commandLink value="respond" style="color:blue"
                       actionListener="#{searchController.buildPhotoComments(photo)}"
                       update=":viewPhotoFrmId"
                       oncomplete="PF('viewPhotoDlgWidget').show();" />&nbsp;

        <p:commandLink value="delete" style="color:blue"
                       actionListener="#{imageController.deletePhoto(photo)}"
                       update="profilePhotos"
                       rendered="#{photo.account.id eq user.account.id}" />
    </p:panelGrid>
</p:dataScroller>
```

This is the result that contains both images and videos: 
[image]

Comment: Try this tag  <p:datascroller  scrollHeight="100"/>

Comment: It did not work I will try with css styles and so on and if find a way I will post it...

Comment: Did you found a solution?